# How to know what object the cursor is located in pixi.js

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

How to know what object the cursor is located?
Analog flash events mouseover-mouseout.  pixi.js v3.0.7

Answer (score 2):

Working with 2d objects you can rely on pixi object callbacks, like in [this example](http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/examples/6/) or there:

```
var bunny = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);

// enable the bunny to be responsive to mouse and touch events      
bunny.interactive = true;

// this button mode hand cursor appears when you rollover the bunny with your mouse
bunny.buttonMode = true;

bunny.mousedown = bunny.touchstart = function(data) { this.dragging = true; }

bunny.mouseup = bunny.mouseupoutside = bunny.touchend = 
bunny.touchendoutside = function(data) { this.dragging = false; }

bunny.mousemove = bunny.touchmove = function(data) { if(this.dragging) drag(); }

bunny.mouseover = function(data) {}

bunny.mouseout = function(data) {}
```

In case you want to emulate 3d-world with object picking you need a thing called **raycaster**. Three.js library has built-in one.